# Migrating djangorestframework to 2.X.X

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, migrating

I've inherited a substantial django code base from a previous developer. We're using django-rest-framework for our api, but unfortunately the version we have is 0.4.0. I've searched for documentation on the old version and have come up empty. Specifically, the code mostly uses `djangorestframework.resources.ModelResource`, `FormResource`, and `djangorestframework.views.ListModelView`. I'd be willing to look into porting the code to version 2.X.X, but I haven't found any good resources on how to do that without breaking everything.

My Question:
Does anyone know where I can find either docs for version 0.4.0 or some helpful resource on porting my codebase over to use the new version?

Comment: You can download the 0.4.0 package here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorestframework/0.4.0 . The documentation is in the /doc folder, you need to build it with Sphinx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with fasouto.

Also you can clone the 0.4.x github branch https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/tree/0.4.X.

Use sphinx (http://sphinx-doc.org/tutorial.html) in order to build docs.